# Full Calendar shows horizontal bar on smaller screen

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar [here](http://rezervace.lukasholeczy.eu/new/index.php) and my problem is, that If you will make screen smaller (e.g. 360x640), you will not see whole calendar and you will see vertical scroll bar.

**This how it looks:**

[image]

**And this is my expectation**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 2.1, this is accomplished by using `height: 'auto'` in the settings. As specified in [the documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/height/):

> If "auto" is specified, the view's contents will assume a natural
>   height and no scrollbars will be used. (new in version 2.1.0).